# Can I use JSON.Stringify without it removing the leading zeros

Tags: json, zero, stringify

I have a form that needs to collect the values and turn into a JSON query. However, when I use JSON.stringify it removes the zero off any zip code that begins with zero. Is there any way to prevent that?

Here is a simple version of the code I'm trying to use:

```
var zipcode = 02122;
var data = {
   ZipCode : zipcode
}

var jsonQuery = JSON.stringify(data);
```

Comment: `02122 === 1106`.  Yes, really.

Comment: In case someone browsing this thread someday is generating a 5-digit number for the zipcode, you want `_.random("00000", "99999"));` not `_.random(00000, 99999));`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're making a fundamental mistake:

## Zip codes [are not numbers](https://twitter.com/Schabse/status/348977509217484800)

---

Numbers are for **numeric** data – things that you might add or multiply.
Leading zeroes in a number are intrinsically meaningless, and are not stored anywhere.

Zip codes are **strings** that happen to only contain digits.

Comment: I'm working in Sencha touch and I was saving the zipcode into local storage as a string so I couldn't figure out why it was ending up an integer. I was troubleshooting within the controller logic but it turns out I had the model field set to integer - doh!